# Error Receiving broadcast Intent while installing the apk programatically with in the custom app

Tags: java, android, firebase, broadcastreceiver, apk

Im building an application in which im downloading an apk from firebase using download manager and want to automatically install apk within the app after completing download. but i got an parse error so i researched for some correct code and used it but than it throw an error:

```html
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.amazoneindia.amazone_india, PID: 25402
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Error receiving broadcast Intent { act=android.intent.action.DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE flg=0x80010 pkg=com.amazoneindia.amazone_india (has extras) } in com.amazoneindia.amazone_india.AppDetail$5@288a748
        at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.lambda$getRunnable$0$LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args(LoadedApk.java:1654)
        at android.app.-$$Lambda$LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args$_BumDX2UKsnxLVrE6UJsJZkotuA.run(Unknown Source:2)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:227)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7822)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1026)
     Caused by: android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity  context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag. Is this really what you want?
        at android.app.ContextImpl.startActivity(ContextImpl.java:978)
        at android.app.ContextImpl.startActivity(ContextImpl.java:944)
        at android.content.ContextWrapper.startActivity(ContextWrapper.java:394)
        at com.amazoneindia.amazone_india.AppDetail$5.onReceive(AppDetail.java:287)
        at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.lambda$getRunnable$0$LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args(LoadedApk.java:1623)
        at android.app.-$$Lambda$LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args$_BumDX2UKsnxLVrE6UJsJZkotuA.run(Unknown Source:2) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:227) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7822) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1026)
```

here is my install apk code

```html
   private final String APP_INSTALL_PATH = "\"application/vnd.android.package-archive\"";

        public void installAPK(String destination, Uri uri, Context context) {

            BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
                @Override
                public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N){

                        Uri fileProvider = FileProvider.getUriForFile(
                                context,
                                BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider",
                                new File(destination));

                        Intent install = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                        install.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
                        install.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                        install.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_NOT_UNKNOWN_SOURCE, true);
                        install.setData(fileProvider) ;
                        context.startActivity(install);
                        context.unregisterReceiver(this);

                    } else {

                        Intent install = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                        install.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                        install.setDataAndType(
                                uri,
                                APP_INSTALL_PATH
                        );
                        context.startActivity(install);
                        context.unregisterReceiver(this);


                    }


                }


            };

            context.registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter(DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE));


}
```

here is code for downloadapk():

```html
  //installtion permission

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            if (!getPackageManager().canRequestPackageInstalls()) {
                startActivityForResult(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_UNKNOWN_APP_SOURCES).setData(Uri.parse(String.format("package:%s", getPackageName()))), 1234);
            } else {
            }
        }

        //Storage Permission

        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 1);
        }

        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 1);
        }

        final ProgressDialog progressBarDialog= new ProgressDialog(this);
        progressBarDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
        progressBarDialog.setTitle("Downloading...");
        progressBarDialog.setProgress(0);

        String destination = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS) + "/";
        String fileName = Common.Apkname+".apk";
        destination += fileName;
        final Uri uri = Uri.parse("file://" + destination);

        //Delete update file if exists
        File file = new File(destination);
        if (file.exists())
            //file.delete() - test this, I think sometimes it doesnt work
            file.delete();

        String url = Common.Url;
        DownloadManager.Request r = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(url));
        r.setDestinationInExternalFilesDir(this,Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, Common.Apkname+".apk");
        r.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
        DownloadManager dm = (DownloadManager)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
        r.setDestinationUri(uri);
        final long downloadId =dm.enqueue(r);

        String finalDestination = destination;
        new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {


                boolean downloading = true;


                while (downloading) {

                    DownloadManager.Query q = new DownloadManager.Query();
                    q.setFilterById(downloadId);

                    Cursor cursor = dm.query(q);
                    cursor.moveToFirst();
                    int bytes_downloaded = cursor.getInt(cursor
                            .getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_BYTES_DOWNLOADED_SO_FAR));
                    int bytes_total = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_TOTAL_SIZE_BYTES));

                    if (cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_STATUS)) == DownloadManager.STATUS_SUCCESSFUL) {
                        downloading = false;
                    }

                    final double dl_progress = (int) ((bytes_downloaded * 100l) / bytes_total);


                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                        @Override
                        public void run() {

                            progressBarDialog.setProgress((int) dl_progress);
                            progressBarDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);

                        }
                    });
                    cursor.close();
                }

                progressBarDialog.dismiss();
                installAPK();
            }
        }).start();
        progressBarDialog.show();
```